# Deprecation: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy without making it number aware is deprecated

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 4.3.8 and I can't find any information about thoses deprecations :

> User Deprecated: Creating Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy without making it number aware is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0.
>
> Creating Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy without making it number aware is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0.

I searched in stacktrace and found this :

```
class UnderscoreNamingStrategy implements NamingStrategy
{
private const DEFAULT_PATTERN      = '/(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])/';
private const NUMBER_AWARE_PATTERN = '/(?<=[a-z0-9])([A-Z])/';

/**
 * Underscore naming strategy construct.
 *
 * @param int $case CASE_LOWER | CASE_UPPER
 */
public function __construct($case = CASE_LOWER, bool $numberAware = false)
{
    if (! $numberAware) {
        @trigger_error(
            'Creating ' . self::class . ' without making it number aware is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0.',
            E_USER_DEPRECATED
        );
    }

    $this->case    = $case;
    $this->pattern = $numberAware ? self::NUMBER_AWARE_PATTERN : self::DEFAULT_PATTERN;
}
```

In this class, the constructor is always called without params, so $numberAware is always false.

This class is called in file which has been auto generated by the Symfony Dependency Injection, so I can't "edit" it ...

I thought maybe it was in doctrine.yaml :

```
doctrine:
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

But I have not found any option to allow the number aware :(

Comment: Just make a fresh 4.4.0 (just released, yea) project and doctrine.yaml has "naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware" in it.  Try tweaking yours.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

In most cases I would just answer this sort of question with a comment but I suspect other developers might run into this issue.  I poked around a bit and could not find any explicit documentation on this issue.  Perhaps because the DoctrineBundle is under the control of the Doctrine folks and not the Symfony developers.  Or maybe I am just a bad searcher.

In any event, between 4.3 and 4.4 the service name for the underscore naming strategy was changed.

```
# doctrine.yaml
orm:
  # 4.3
  naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
  # 4.4
  naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
```

And a deprecated message was added to warn developers to change the name.  Would have been nice if the message was just a tiny bit more explicit but oh well.
So if you are upgrading an existing app to 4.4 and beyond then you will probably need to manually edit your doctrine.yaml file to make the depreciation message go away.

Some more info (thanks @janh) on why the change was made:
https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.8.x/UPGRADE.md#deprecated-number-unaware-doctrineormmappingunderscorenamingstrategy
https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7855

Still not really clear on why "they" chose to do things this way but oh well.
You probably want to run "bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql" just to see if this impacts your database column names and adjust accordingly.  The changes has been out for several weeks now and there does not seem to be many howls of outrage over the change so I guess most column names don't have embedded numbers.  So far at least.

Comment: old strategy change (wrongly) for example $singleMd5Key to single_payu_md5key and new one (correctly) single_payu_md5_key. but coz that is BC change we have all that mess.

Comment: @TomekKobyliński Have you been able to find any documentation on this besides the code itself?  Still struggling to understand why the naming convention would change (and thus possibly force a database schema change) when Doctrine 3 arrives.  Just seems like both approaches would be supported.

Comment: There is no need for change database schema, jsut need add explicite column name in field declaration.

Comment: So instead of forcing a database schema change you have to manually update your entity mappings?  Not sure which is worse and it doesn't really address the question of why change at all.  No problem with providing a more "correct" strategy but I still don't understand why the original strategy is "wrong" in any relevant sense.

Comment: Came here after diving into this deprecation (found by running phpunit) as well. Would be good to link to the recipe yaml in the answer, as that confirms the proposed fix: https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/2.0/config/packages/doctrine.yaml

Comment: @Cerad There's something in doctrine's upgrade info: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.8.x/UPGRADE.md#deprecated-number-unaware-doctrineormmappingunderscorenamingstrategy I think https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7855 is the relevant issue.

Comment: So how do we get rid of the deprecation log message? I tried to add underscore_number_aware, but returns ServiceNotFoundException

Comment: I assume you mean doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware?  Make sure your composer update completed cleanly and maybe try the ever popular  bin/console cache:clear

Comment: Actually, using doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware removes the deprecation message as suggested by @Cerad

Comment: from 4.3 changing to # 4.4
  naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware

makes some of the existing tables non readable, you have to recreate them. If you already have data in there it may be a problem to fix

Answer (score 1):

For those who works with symfony4.3 and still want this warning disapear you can add add new new service defintion in **service.yaml**

```
    custom_doctrine_orm_naming_strategy_underscore:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy
    arguments:
        - 0
        - true
```

and change the configuration of **doctrine.yaml** like this:

```
orm:
    naming_strategy: custom_doctrine_orm_naming_strategy_underscore
```

before going straight forward committing this change I would suggest you to verify that passing `true` to the `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy` doesn't affect the expected behavior of your code.

```
// class UnderscoreNamingStrategy
/**
 * Underscore naming strategy construct.
 *
 * @param int $case CASE_LOWER | CASE_UPPER
 */
public function __construct($case = CASE_LOWER, bool $numberAware = false)
{
    if (! $numberAware) {
        @trigger_error(
            'Creating ' . self::class . ' without making it number aware is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0.',
            E_USER_DEPRECATED
        );
    }

    $this->case    = $case;
    $this->pattern = $numberAware ? self::NUMBER_AWARE_PATTERN : self::DEFAULT_PATTERN;
}
```

**Quick hint:**

passing `true` to the c'tor will make the class use the `NUMBER_AWARE_PATTERN` instead of the `DEFAULT_PATTERN`

```
private const DEFAULT_PATTERN      = '/(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])/';
private const NUMBER_AWARE_PATTERN = '/(?<=[a-z0-9])([A-Z])/';
```

Comment: If you're switching to the new number-aware strategy anyway, then why not just update the strategy in Doctrine config instead of using this hack?