# Deprecation warnings after upgrading Symfony 4.3.9 to 4.4.1/5.0

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I had a deprecation-free Symfony 3.4.9 installation. So I upgraded the FW to 4.1.1. Now I got 9 deprecation warnings all coming from vendor libraries:

- Creating Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy without making it number aware is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0.
- The "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4, use "ErrorListener" instead.
- The Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory class is deprecated since doctrine/persistence 1.3 and will be removed in 2.0. Use \Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory instead.
- The Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService class is deprecated since doctrine/persistence 1.3 and will be removed in 2.0. Use \Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService instead.
- The Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager class is deprecated since doctrine/persistence 1.3 and will be removed in 2.0. Use \Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager instead.
- The Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository class is deprecated since doctrine/persistence 1.3 and will be removed in 2.0. Use \Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectRepository instead.
- The Doctrine\Common\PropertyChangedListener class is deprecated since doctrine/persistence 1.3 and will be removed in 2.0. Use \Doctrine\Persistence\PropertyChangedListener instead.
- The "twig.exception_controller" configuration key has been deprecated in Symfony 4.4, set it to "null" and use "framework.error_controller" configuration key instead. (x2)

Is this "normal" or there is any problems in my composer.json file ? I double checked and can't see any dependency that has any "fixed" setting.

I even deleted the full vendor folder and downloaded again as I thought there could be any "garbage" left, with same result.

My composer.json file:

```
{
    "type" : "project",
    "license" : "proprietary",
    "require" : {
        "php" : "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype" : "*",
        "ext-iconv" : "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "^5.2",
        "symfony/apache-pack" : "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset" : "4.4.*",
        "symfony/console" : "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv" : "4.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language" : "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex" : "^1.1",
        "symfony/form" : "4.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle" : "4.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "^3.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack" : "*",
        "symfony/process" : "4.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle" : "4.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer-pack" : "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation" : "4.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle" : "4.4.*",
        "symfony/validator" : "4.4.*",
        "symfony/web-link" : "4.4.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle" : "^1.1",
        "symfony/yaml" : "4.4.*"
    },
    "require-dev" : {
        "symfony/debug-pack" : "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle" : "^1.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack" : "^1.0",
        "symfony/test-pack" : "*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle" : "4.4.*"
    },
    "config" : {
        "preferred-install" : {
            "*" : "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages" : true,
        "secure-http" : false
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "App\\" : "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "App\\Tests\\" : "tests/"
        },
        "classmap" : [
            "vendor/phpasn1"
        ]
    },
    "replace" : {
        "paragonie/random_compat" : "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype" : "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv" : "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71" : "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70" : "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56" : "*"
    },
    "conflict" : {
        "symfony/symfony" : "*"
    },
    "extra" : {
        "symfony" : {
            "allow-contrib" : false,
            "require" : "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I checked installed packages with `composer show` and see that at least 2 of the installed packages are relevant with the deprecation list above:

```
(...)
doctrine/orm                        v2.7.0  Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
doctrine/persistence                1.3.3   The Doctrine Persistence project is a set of shared...
(...)
```

So I checked the available versions of these packages with `composer info doctrine/persistence --all` and I saw that it has installed the latest non-dev version:

```
name     : doctrine/persistence
descrip. : The Doctrine Persistence project is a set of shared interfaces and functionality that the different Doctrine object mappers share.
keywords : mapper, object, odm, orm, persistence
versions : dev-master, 2.0.x-dev, 1.3.x-dev, * 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.x-dev, 1.2.0, 1.1.x-dev, 1.1.1, v1.1.0, 1.0.x-dev, v1.0.1, v1.0.0, dev-1.3.x-merge-up-into-master_5df35c38f354a9.94042071, dev-1.3.x-merge-up-into-master_5df33dc289ea03.65167777, dev-1.3.x-merge-up-into-master_5df29d964b0aa5.96685696, dev-github-funding, dev-master-old
(...)
```

Same for `doctrine-orm`.

The GitHub site for doctrine/persistence also seems to corroborate this: https://github.com/doctrine/persistence/releases

So this leads me to think that this is really normal behavior and that in future, when these packages get updated, the deprecation messages will disappear.

**Note on solution**

As anyone who have read the accepted answer will notice, there are still 5 deprecation that cannot be solved just yet. I'll include an answer ASA there are a fix for this. If anyone notices this before me, please fell free to add an answer to this question. Thanks.

Comment: If they are coming from vendor libraries and not your code - then it's normal. You should update the vendors in question and that should fix it. Have in mind that not all libraries are up-to-date with the latest symfony & doctrine deprecations so updating might not fix it right away.

Comment: The problem is... which vendors ? there are multiple packages for doctrine and for twig. AFAIU these are the ones involved. Which ones should I choose in json ?  I just checked... just for doctrine package there are 33.

Comment: The easiest way I've found to deal with this is to start the project in dev mode and go through some pages in your browser. The debug toolbar will show you deprecation notices and you can use the `trace` links to see the stacktrace and pin-point where they come from. :)

Comment: @tftd that could be the case if the deprecations were in my code. But the deprecations are coming from the dependent libraries in Symfony 4.1.1. So this procedure won't help

Comment: Things changed between 4.3 and 4.4.  Remember that you only need to clean up deprecation's before moving to 5.x.  So just plow through and fix like any other though the first one is actually a Doctrine issue and can be fixed with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975182/deprecation-doctrine-orm-mapping-underscorenamingstrategy-without-making-it-num/58976557#58976557

Comment: I just have switched to Symfony 5.0 version and have the same issue. There are exactly the same deprecations messages in my log with doctrine/persistence package as you.

Comment: Please don't delete the question. Even if there is nothing to do, except waiting for vendor updates. I got here via the Doctrine deprecation (about `ObjectManager`) and it helped me to see, whats going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've been able to fix the following. Feel free to edit this if anyone knows how to fix any of the other ones.

1.) From Cerad in the Comments: [Deprecation: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy without making it number aware is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975182/deprecation-doctrine-orm-mapping-underscorenamingstrategy-without-making-it-num/58976557#58976557)

9.) Twig `twig.exception_controller` configuration option: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/UPGRADE-4.4.md#twigbundle

2.) The `ExceptionListener` cleared in when I fixed the above two items, bringing me down to only 5 deprecations

---

Finally the 5 remaining, seem to be known and will be fixed per this:
[Deprecated classes warnings in Symfony 5.0.1 console on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326187/deprecated-classes-warnings-in-symfony-5-0-1-console-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get rid of the `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\*` depreciations until everything is fixed, you can add a `"conflict": { "doctrine/persistence": "1.3.*" }` to your `composer.json` and stay with version 1.2.* of *doctrine/persistence*.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I rather have the messages, or I'll probably forget I have to fix this. :)